# duplicate comment on facebook comment box

Tags: facebook

Facebook comment post auto duplicate content.
How to prevent duplicate facebook comment on facebook comment box. Comments duplicate can be found on [this blog post](http://www.khoahoc.com.vn/giaitri/thu-vien-anh/47647_Nhung-quai-vat-cua-dai-duong.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a known bug with the plugin.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/489244604487290

Hopefully Facebook will find a fix soon.  Add yourself to the "repro" list in the link above to escalate the issue.